# GCC 7 on Mac OS X doesn't find C++ standard library

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew

I have been trying to compile the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
std::cout << "Test compilation" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am using GGC 7 (installed via homebrew) on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Unfortunately, it does not build this simple test program (source file is test.cpp):

```
$ make test.out 
gcc-7   -O0 -g -std=c++1z -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-missing-braces -Wmissing-field-initializers
 -Werror=implicit test.cpp.cpp  -o test.cpp.out

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:

      _main in ccJgvOlx.o

  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:

      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccJgvOlx.o

  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:

      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccJgvOlx.o

  "std::cout", referenced from:

      _main in ccJgvOlx.o

  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&)", referenced from:

      _main in ccJgvOlx.o

  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccJgvOlx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test.out] Error 1
```

The configuration of my GCC is the following:

```
$ gcc-7 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-7
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/7.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/7 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-7 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-checking=release --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 7.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0)
```

What do I need to change in order to have this simple test program compile and run?

Comment: Did it also create a `g++-7` program? I don’t have a Mac to test this on but I ran into a similar issue on my system.

Comment: It was the difference between 'gcc' and 'g++'. Thank you for the comment. I believe they should include a warning for that mistake.

Comment: Indeed, Clang switches automatically to compile C or C++ depending on the source files. So the default `gcc` command on the Mac compiles C++ programs. This is not the case for GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not what what you're doing by attempting to compile a C++ program with a C compiler.

According to my experience, there shouldn't be such a problem if you use `g++`:

```
g++-7   -O0 -g -std=c++1z -pedantic -Wall test.cpp.cpp  -o test.cpp.out
```

I suggest that you change the rule from

```
test.out: test.cpp
    ${CC} ${CPPFLAGS} ...
```

To

```
test.out: test.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CPPFLAGS} ...
```

in your makefile to solve this problem.

Comment: I know that I expect the main program for the **G**NU **C**ompiler **C**ollection to be able to determine what options to pass the linker, *especially since it successfully compiles C++ code into object files*; the only step that fails is linking. Maybe if it still stood for GNU C Compiler, I'd agree with your first paragraph. Definitely if it acted like only a C compiler, but it works until all but the last step of compilation (which, unfortunately, is also the step that generates the most cryptic errors). I consider this a borderline bug in GCC.